# Jenkins shows "No changes in any of the builds."

Tags: jenkins, git, bitbucket

## Description

Jenkins job was made and configured to build release branch which already existed and had changes on it before first build. Job also monitors for push on BitBucket and starts building if something is pushed to the release branch.

Problem is we didn't made any changes on release branch, instead we were rebasing it on development and pushing it which triggered builds but it shows *"No changes in any of the builds."* in **Changes** menu.

## Question

Is there special configuration for Jenkins which allows it to handle rebase commits and show changes that occurred to that commit comparing to previous build?

Comment: Was the rebase a fast-forward one? Do you see a merge commit for it in `git log` (after the last development branch commit being merged)?

Comment: @DanCornilescu this is what it shows for rebase, I don't see merge commit.
`f7398e22 (origin/release/2.0.1, release/2.0.1) HEAD@{16}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/release/2.0.1

f7398e22 (origin/release/2.0.1, release/2.0.1) HEAD@{17}: rebase: NOT-600: Updated version number

751fd43c (HEAD -> development, origin/feature/NOT-594, origin/development) HEAD@{18}: rebase: checkout development

b450c488 HEAD@{19}: checkout: moving from development to release/2.0.1`

Comment: Is [JENKINS-17411](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17411) describing your scenario?

Comment: @DanCornilescu not really. Jenkins does build, but changes section is always empty.

Answer (score 4):

## Temporary workaround

Instead of calculating changes between builds compare changes against specific branch.

1. Open job configuration
2. Go to **Source Code Management** -> **Git** -> **Additional Behaviours**
3. Add **Calculate changelog against a specific branch**
4. Enter name of repository (origin in my case), and branch (master in my case)

Now instead of showing only new changes, each build will show all commits in release branch that are different comparing to master.